# Ошибка в кодировке при открытии страницы

Tags: python, парсер, urllib

Возникает ошибка:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   5-11: ordinal not in range(128)

Каким способом можно декодировать строку с адресом в кодировке 'utf-8'   ?

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse   import quote
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https://anapa.russianrealty.ru/Продажа-квартир/')
x = BeautifulSoup(text)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз используете `bs4`, то почему бы и `requests` не задействовать?

```
# pip install requests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
rs = requests.get('https://anapa.russianrealty.ru/Продажа-квартир/')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
print(root)
```

---

Но если таки хотите через `urlopen`, то [нужно обработать url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269491/5909792) так, чтобы в нем были только ascii символы:

```
from urllib.parse import quote, urlsplit, urlunsplit

def get_ascii_url(url: str) -> str:
    url = list(urlsplit(url))
    url[2] = quote(url[2])
    return urlunsplit(url)

url = 'https://anapa.russianrealty.ru/Продажа-квартир/'
url = get_ascii_url(url)
print(url)  # https://anapa.russianrealty.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80/

html = urlopen(url)
...
```

---

**PS.** [накидал еще пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c66b39c43a21917ba347b9956d90a688a3446fbc/iri_to_uri__get_ascii_url.py#L16), который покрывает всякие нюансы:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse
import re

def url_encode_non_ascii(b: bytes) -> bytes:
    return re.sub(b'[\x80-\xFF]', lambda c: b'%%%02x' % ord(c.group(0)), b)


# SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391299/5909792
def iri_to_uri(iri: str) -> str:
    parts = urlparse(iri)
    return urlunparse(
        part.encode('idna') if parti == 1 else url_encode_non_ascii(part.encode('utf-8'))
        for parti, part in enumerate(parts)
    ).decode('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://anapa.russianrealty.ru/Продажа-квартир/'
    new_url = iri_to_uri(url)
    print(new_url)
    assert new_url == 'https://anapa.russianrealty.ru/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80/'

    url = 'http://www.a\u0131b.com/a\u0131b'
    new_url = iri_to_uri(url)
    print(new_url)
    assert new_url == 'http://www.xn--ab-hpa.com/a%c4%b1b'

    url = 'https://ya.ru'
    new_url = iri_to_uri(url)
    print(new_url)
    assert new_url == 'https://ya.ru'

    url = 'https://google.com'
    new_url = iri_to_uri(url)
    print(new_url)
    assert new_url == 'https://google.com'

    url = 'http://домены.рф'
    new_url = iri_to_uri(url)
    print(new_url)
    assert new_url == 'http://xn--d1acufc5f.xn--p1ai'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое )

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь вывести не текст со страницы, а текст с модуля **BeautifulSoup**, 
для начала сварите суп:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
```

А потом уже можете разбирать его на составляющие или вывести сразу весь код страницы:

```
print(soup)
```

Я бы посоветовал писать так вообще:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://anapa.russianrealty.ru/Продажа-квартир/'
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: `r = session.get(url)` а сессию не создали :)

Comment: @gil9red пардон, поправил))